# C#Desktop Push Notifications

Tags: c#, push-notification, desktop-application, chromium, cefsharp

I am making a c# application that uses cefsharp to display website content which contains desktop push notifications. The notifications works fine in Google Chrome Browser, but they doesn't work in CefSharp. I tried to find up-to-date information about push notifications support, but all i find is posts from 2014 saying that it doesn't support it. However, it's 2017 now and I am wondering does latest version support desktop push notifications ? If not, is there any way to implement them manually ? Thank you.

Comment: CEF does not implement that particular API. CefSharp is just a wrapper. You would have to implement the API yourself and provide notifications to your .Net app. Read the general usage guide for info on JavaScript binding.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @BernardDanken did you solved this?